# browser.find keeps returning undefined for firefox add on

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to write a basic firefox add on that finds a word on a webpage.
I've wrapped that up in an anonymous function and it's in addon.js.
I keep getting the error that browser.find is undefined. Is "browser" just a variable that is a reference to the browser and if so how do I create that reference? Thx.

addon.js

```
(function () {

  function found(results) {
  console.log(`There were: ${results.count} matches.`);
  if (results.count > 0) {
    browser.find.highlightResults();
  }
}

   browser.find.find("P").then(found);

})();
```

manifest.json:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "add on test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "testing add on",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "*://*.mozilla.org/*" ],
      "js": [ "addon.js" ],
      "css":  ["addon.css"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
       "notifications",
       "activeTab",
       "webNavigation",
       "find"
   ]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `find` is not part of the API functions that content scripts can access.
You can find a full list of those [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#WebExtension_APIs)

You can implement this functionality using a background script.
When the content script is loaded, you could send a message to the background script to trigger the search and the highlighting of the results.

Here is an example:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "add on test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "testing add on",
  "background" : { "scripts": ["background.js"]},
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "*://*.mozilla.org/*" ],
      "js": [ "addon.js" ],
      "css":  ["addon.css"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
       "find"
   ]
}
```

background.js

```
function found(rsp, results) {
  if (results.count > 0) {
    browser.find.highlightResults();
  }
  rsp(`There were: ${results.count} matches.`);
}
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(req, sender, rsp){
  if(req.cmd == "find"){
    browser.find.find(req.toFind).then(found.bind(this, rsp));
    return true;
  }
});
```

addon.js

```
browser.runtime.sendMessage({
    cmd: "find",
    toFind: "P"
}, function(msg){
    console.log(msg)
});
```

Comment: Thx @Titus. I'm still a bit unsure re: the difference between content and background scripts (i've read the docs). Also, I've got the background script working by changing the manifest and browser.find.find("A") returns all the letter A's on the about:debugging page - but not on any other tab. I did add "tabs" to permissions but had no effect. thx

Comment: @Mike `find` searches a single tab, if you want to search on a specific tab you'll have to pass a second argument to the function with options that specify that. You can take a look at the [DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/find/find) for more details.